# WordPress Taxonomy Query

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I have a post type "product" and a taxonomy ("product_cat"), on the single view of this post type, I want a `WP_Query` which lists posts by the following criteria:

- Three posts per page
- Only posts in the "product" post type
- Exclude the current post
- Has any "product_cat" taxonomy term(s) the current post has

I have achieved this by using the following query:

```
global $post;

$taxonomy = 'product_cat';

$have_you_read_query = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => m_explode(get_terms($taxonomy), 'slug')
      )
    )
  )
);
```

If you're wondering what the `m_explode` function does here's that:

```
function m_explode(array $array, $key = '') {
  if( !is_array($array) or $key == '') return;
  $output = array();
  foreach( $array as $v ) {
    if( !is_object($v) ) {
      return;
    }
    $output[] = $v->$key;
  }
  return $output;
}
```

The only problem I'm having with this is when there are no posts at all which have any "product_cat" terms attached to it, it gives the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Localhost\wordpress\wp-includes\query.php on line 2473
```

The problem has me stumped, it's not really a huge problem, but it's just really annoying me so if anyone has any idea it would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted this in the end, just in case anyone ever needs it, here's what I ended up using:

```
<?php
  global $post;

  $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

  $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
?>

<?php if ($terms && ! is_wp_error($terms)) : ?>

  <?php
    $terms_array = array();

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $terms_array[] = $term->slug;
    }

    $have_you_read_query = new WP_Query(
      array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $terms_array
          )
        )
      )
    );
  ?>

  <?php if($have_you_read_query->have_posts()) : ?>

    <ul>
      <?php while($have_you_read_query->have_posts()) : $have_you_read_query->the_post(); ?>

        <li>
          <?php the_title(); ?>
        </li>

      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>

  <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check on `m_explode()`:

```
$terms = m_explode(get_terms($taxonomy), 'slug');

if( isset( $terms ) ){
    // your query
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and it hasn't made a difference unfortunately.